# Custom Progress Bar in Google Forms for Course Selection

Tags: google-forms, google-sites, google-apps-for-education

For a myriad of reasons, my school wants to try and use google forms to have students sign up for courses for the next school year. We have the format that we want to try and use, but students should only be able to select a certain number of courses (all that will fit on their schedule). I would like to know if there is a way to create a custom progress bar for students that fills (maybe along the side) in blocks as students fill in their schedules.

Even if I have to make a website with the form in the middle and the bar on the side, I would like to know if anyone has done anything with this before. My first thought was an update graph, linked to the specific student, but I could not figure out how to get that to work without submitting the form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The data in a Google Form is not saved until the Submit button is pressed.  Also, there is no way to dynamically limit selections or verify they have not selected duplicates when using Google Forms.  You can get complex with branching questions, but I would not recommend this.

You probably want to use Google Apps Script (GAS) to create a custom form and include that it the HTML page you generate.  If you are up to this, GAS is basically javascript.  You can generate a form to place in an iFrame or supply the link outright.  Just deploy it as web app.  If your students have domain accounts you could deploy it to run as them and then collect their information base don their login.You may want to start [here: Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) and then look at [HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) as a starting point.

Once you have specific questions, create a new post and be sure to include your code.